# Reusing component in react with dynamic router links

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to reuse a component in react to render a table view from mysql. I have my navigation generated by a query that lists all of the tables in the database.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import './navigation.scss';

class Navigation extends Component {
    state = {
        items: []
    }

    Normalize = name => {
        return name.split('_')
            .map(part => part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1))
            .join(' ');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3132/api/tables')
            .then(data => {
                return data.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                let tables = json.map((table, index) => {
                    var name = table.table_name;
                    return <li key={index}>
                        <NavLink activeClassName="active-nav" to={'/table/' + name} name={name}>{this.Normalize(name)}</NavLink>
                    </li>;
                })
                this.setState({ tables: tables });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navigation">
                <h2>Tables</h2>
                <Router>
                    <ul>
                        <li><NavLink exact activeClassName="active-nav" to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                        {this.state.tables}
                    </ul>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

The links work in that they update the url and the active class gets assigned. However, the 'view' component never changes after initial page load.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/home/home.component';
import Table from './components/table/table.component';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
                <Route path={"/table/:path"} component={(props) => (<Table {...props} />)}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

Even the static Home route doesn't update when it is active. This is what the Table component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Table extends Component {    
    state = {};
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({tableName: this.props.match.params.path});
    }
    render() {
        return <h1>{this.state.tableName}</h1>
    }    
}
export default Table;
```

What do I have to do to get the 'Table' component to render/update?

Edit:
Tried a functional component as suggested in the comment as such and no luck

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Table = props => {
    return <h1>{props.match.params.path}</h1>
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Make your table a controlled component, stateless functional component, pass it props and let them render.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, place your code on CodeSandBox.io, i can review there.

Comment: @its4zahoor I did try that. No luck. Updating with what I wrote.